Need to create a Azure script to take snapshots based on the tags value and auto deletes the snapshots after 7 days with multiple subscriptions
I need some link which can drive through this from scratch
Install-Module -Name Az -AllowClobber -Force

# Login to Azure Account (if not running in an automated environment)
Connect-AzAccount

# Define variables
$resourceGroup = "your-resource-group"
$daysOld = 30  # Number of days after which snapshots will be deleted

# Calculate the threshold date
$thresholdDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$daysOld)
 
$snapshots = Get-AzSnapshot -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup


foreach ($snapshot in $snapshots) {
    if ($snapshot.TimeCreated -lt $thresholdDate) {
        Write-Host "Deleting snapshot: $($snapshot.Name) created on $($snapshot.TimeCreated)"
        Remove-AzSnapshot -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -SnapshotName $snapshot.Name -Force
    }
}


What link. Clarify what do you want?
This question is really unclear! What does "dive through this" mean?

Please read [ask], and then edit your question to provide a [mcve] - right now, your question is unclear (there's no specific question, actually)

Here is the updated PowerShell script to create a Azure Snapshot based on tag match and delete the snapshot after 7 Days

Note: To automatically delete snapshots after 7 days, you need to schedule this script using an Azure Automation Account. It will allow the script to run at scheduled time and date to identify snapshots to check the expiration and need to be deleted.

$subscriptions = @('Subscription1','Subscription2') 
$deleteAfterDays = 7
$currentDate = Get-Date
$expirationDateForDeletion = $currentDate.AddDays(-$deleteAfterDays)

Write-Output "Expiration Date for Deletion: $expirationDateForDeletion"

foreach ($subscription in $subscriptions) {
   Set-AzContext -Subscription $subscription
   $disks = Get-AzDisk | Where-Object { $_.Tags[$tagName] -eq $tagValue }
    foreach ($disk in $disks) {
        $snapshotName = "$($disk.Name)-snapshot-$(Get-Date -Format 'yyyyMMddHHmmss')"
        $resourceGroupName = $disk.ResourceGroupName
        $snapshotConfig = New-AzSnapshotConfig -SourceUri $disk.Id -CreateOption Copy -Location $disk.Location
        $snapshot = New-AzSnapshot -Snapshot $snapshotConfig -SnapshotName $snapshotName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName
        $expirationDate = (Get-Date).AddDays($deleteAfterDays).ToString('yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ')
        $tags = @{"DeleteAfter" = $expirationDate}
        New-AzSnapshotUpdateConfig -Tag $tags | Update-AzSnapshot -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -SnapshotName $snapshotName
        Write-Output "Snapshot $snapshotName created and tagged with expiration date $expirationDate."
    }

#Deletion Script

    $snapshots = Get-AzSnapshot
    foreach ($snapshot in $snapshots) {
        $timeCreated = $snapshot.TimeCreated
        Write-Output "Snapshot Name: $($snapshot.Name), TimeCreated: $timeCreated" 
        if ($timeCreated -eq $expirationDateForDeletion) {  
            Remove-AzSnapshot -ResourceGroupName $snapshot.ResourceGroupName -SnapshotName $snapshot.Name -Force
            Write-Output "Snapshot $($snapshot.Name) deleted (created on $timeCreated, matches 7 days ago)."
        }
        else {
            
            Write-Output "Snapshot $($snapshot.Name) skipped (created on $timeCreated, does not match exactly 7 days ago)."
        }
    }
}

Deletion script
  $snapshots = Get-AzSnapshot

    foreach ($snapshot in $snapshots) {
       
        $timeCreated = $snapshot.TimeCreated

        Write-Output "Snapshot Name: $($snapshot.Name), TimeCreated: $timeCreated"
        
        if ($timeCreated -eq $expirationDateForDeletion) {
            
            Remove-AzSnapshot -ResourceGroupName $snapshot.ResourceGroupName -SnapshotName $snapshot.Name -Force
            Write-Output "Snapshot $($snapshot.Name) deleted (created on $timeCreated, matches 7 days ago)."
        }
        else {
            
            Write-Output "Snapshot $($snapshot.Name) skipped (created on $timeCreated, does not match exactly 7 days ago)."
        }
    }

Output:

Refer: Follow the Stack link to schedule the script in an Azure Automation Account.

What question are you answering? The OP has asked a question that doesn't make any sense, and showed some PowerShell without any explanation. The OP needs to edit their question.

Hi @DavidMakogon, I answered the thread-based Question heading, I do agree with your comment.

Posting a requirement is not a valid question. And there is no valid question in the title, nor in the single-line-of-text in the question body. This site is not for people to post requirements and have others implement those requirements (that requires a consultant). Questions need to be specific with a [mcve]. See How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?, as well as Why is "Can someone help me?" not a useful question?

Just close-vote as "needs more focus" - along with possibly a helpful comment to the OP guiding them on how to improve the question. But please don't post custom solutions with no specific question.

Somehow I got what i wanted to achieved, Major credits to Venkat.
